# What is ..TABLENAME used for on SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example query is like `SELECT * FROM ..EMPLOYEES`. What does it mean this query style on SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it SQL Server query syntax.

Full syntax would be :

```
select *
from Databasename.schema.tablename -- (first two .. optional) will run on selected database with default schema
```

Where first `.` denotes for database name, second `.` for schema

If you are running with this :

```
select * 
from ..EMPLOYEES
```

So, it will run for default schema `dbo` with selected database on top.

Comment: Adding one would typically specify 1 or 2-part names when querying tables in the current database.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. degenerate form of the 3 part naming convention with the first 2 elements just left out.

Comment: *"it will run for default schema `dbo`"* Slight correction, but it would run with the default schema for the `USER`. `dbo` is not always the default schema.

Answer (score 0):

Transact-SQL references to the name of a database object can be a four-part name in `server.[database].[schema].object` form and as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#multipart-names) *... to omit intermediate nodes, use periods to indicate these positions. The following table shows the valid formats of object names.*.

So

`SELECT * FROM ..EMPLOYEES`

is a valid T-SQL statement. The `database` and `schema` names are omitted and the default database and schema for the login are used.